# retreive image on clicking image name through ajax in codeignitor from database

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, codeigniter, image-gallery

i am making gallery in codeignitor. i have retrived list of image names from database  on view page. now i want to get image on clicking name through ajax. i am not that much good with code. kindly help me with fetch gallery function. any help is much appreciated. thanks in advance. 
    this is my code for fetchng image names:

```
          <?php
                      //$i=1;
                      foreach($data as $row)
                      {
                        ?>
                        <img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/<?php echo $row->imagefiles;?>' height='30px' width='30px'>
                        <span class="username">
                            <a id="view_gallery" class="view_gallery" href="javascript:void(0);" id="<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></a>
                        </span>
                        <hr>
                      <?php }
                    ?>
```

and this is my script, i need further help with code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( ".view_gallery" ).click(function() {

        id = $(this).attr('id');
    /*    alert(userid);*/
           $.ajax({
                url     : '<?php  echo base_url('fetch_gallery_data') ;?>',
                method  : 'post',
                data    : {id : id},
                success : function(res){
                  $('.disp_gallery').html(res);
                }
              })

    });
    </script>
```

here is my fetch gallery function  in controller ,

```
  public function fetch_gallery_data()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $where = $id;
        $result = $this->App_model->gallery_model('gallery','id',$where);
        $data = '';
        if(count($result) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
            {
                $files = json_decode($value->imagefile);
                if($value->id > 0)
                {
                    $data .= "<div class='col-md-3' style='border:1px solid gray; margin:20px; padding:20px; ' id='".$id."''>";
                    $data .= "<a >";
                    $data .= "<img src='".base_url()."assets\uploads/seo-business-quotes-6.jpg' height='150' width='150'><br>";

                    $data .= "</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach ($files as $key => $value) 
                    {
                        $data .= "<div class='col-md-3' style='border:1px solid gray; margin:20px; padding:20px; '>";
                        $data .= "<img src=".base_url()."assets\uploads/".$value." height='150' width='150'><br>";
                        $data .= "</div>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $data .= 'No Records.';
        }
        echo $data;

    }
```

Comment: disp_gallery where is your dom?

Comment: i have just made simple div to get response like this . <div class="post disp_gallery row">
                    </div>

Comment: what response come? html or json?

Comment: This is your controller code ??

Comment: no, its view code where i want to show images by clicking names, i want help with function in controller @BoominathanElango

Comment: can you show your fetch_gallery_data controller code here

Comment: i have edited above in questions, please have a look at my function, it might need lots of corrections . @BoominathanElango

Comment: can you get the response from server now ?? only image not appears or there is no response occurs ?

Comment: no response. i am not good with code,  it would be great if you can write function for me. @BoominathanElango

Answer (score 0):

Change the slashes you mentioned in the controller then try

```
$data .= "<img src='".base_url()."assets/uploads/seo-business-quotes-6.jpg' height='150' width='150'><br>";
```

Here also change slash and single quotes

```
$data .= "<img src='".base_url()."assets/uploads/".$value."' height='150' width='150'><br>";
```